# Mysql table records are displayed in a crooked manner

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created a table in MySQL but when I display the table, some records are displayed in a crooked manner.

Here's the table displayed:

```
select * from air_passenger_profile;

+------------+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+
| profile_id | password | first_name | last_name | address                         | mobile_number | email_id            |
+------------+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+
| PFL001     | PFL001   | LATHA      | SANKAR    | 123  BROAD  CROSS ST,CHENNAI-48 |    9876543210 |  LATHA@GMAIL.COM    |
| PFL002     |  PFL002  |  ARUN      |  PRAKASH  |  768  2ND STREET,BENGALURU-20   |    8094564243 | ARUN@AOL.COM        |
| PFL003     |  PFL003  | AMIT       |  VIKARAM  |  43 5TH STREET,KOCHI-84         |    9497996990 | AMIT@AOL.COM        |
| PFL004     |  PFL004  |  AARTHI    |  RAMESH   |  343 6TH STREET,HYDERABAD-76    |    9595652530 |  AARTHI@GMAIL.COM   |
| PFL005     |  PFL005  |  SIVA      |  KUMAR    | 125 8TH STREET,CHENNAI-46       |    9884416986 | SIVA@GMAIL.COM      |
| PFL006     | PFL006   | RAMESH     |  BABU     |  109 2ND CROSS ST,KOCHI-12      |    9432198760 |  RAMESH@GMAIL.COM   |
| PFL007     | PFL007   | GAYATHRI   |  RAGHU    | 23 2ND CROSS ST,BENGALURU-12    |    8073245678 | GAYATHRI@GMAIL.COM  |
| PFL008     | PFL008   |  GANESH    | KANNAN    | 45 3RD ST,HYDERABAD-21          |    9375237890 | GANESH@GMAIL.COM    |
+------------+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Please add an actual question.

Comment: How does the data get into the table? please provide an example

Comment: Maybe they are spaces. Try to [lrim](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) spaces: `select ltrim(password) from ...`.

Comment: Run this: SELECT '<' + first_name + ">' to see the leading and/or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You place it into your database with spaces. At the point where you insert your variables into the databse, you could use PHP's [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) function, or [MySQL's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), to store it without the spaces.

To correct your current values:

```
UPDATE air_passenger_profile SET first_name = TRIM(first_name), etc...
```

Comment: And maybe also remove duplicated spaces within the text strings via `REPLACE(TRIM(col), '  ', ' ')`

Comment: IMO that should be done in your sanatizing, not in a query. And also not really pat of the question. But not a bad thing to implement .